# Coating fruit before adding to a cake

Tags: baking, cake, apples

I recently had an apple cake at a restaurant that was delicious.  It tasted like a gooey-er version of a spice cake with apples and coconuts.  I think I can recreate this at home using a box spice cake mix.  I have three questions.  I know to keep the fruit spaced through-out the cake, I want to dust it with flour.  Since it's a box mix, I'll probably use either plain or create a spiced flour to dust the apple bits.  Will that flour cause me to increase the liquid in the cake?  Will it make the apples taste flour-y?  And should I cook the apples (at least partially) before dusting and adding or will the cook enough when baking the cake?

Comment: Dust them with some of the cake mix itself, if you are going to use a mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by SAJ14SAJ, you can dust the apple pieces with some of the cake mix. There is no need to change the proportions asked for by the cake mix box. You also do not need to cook the apples ahead, but you can slice them quite thinly or cut in small pieces to ensure that they are cooked enough.

Comment: I didn't originally mention using the mix because I wasn't sure if it would use too much of the mix and cause it to be too wet.  I had planned on slicing the apples into very small pieces, but it's good to know they should cook enough during the baking.  :)